# Find $\gcd$ of $(2016)^{ 2017}-1$ and $(2016)^{ 2016}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find $\gcd$ of $(2016)^{ 2017}-1$ and $(2016)^{ 2016}-1$? 
My teacher told me that $\gcd$ of $m^{m+1}-1$ and $m^m-1$ is $m-1$.
By using the above result I got $\gcd$ as $2015$. But I want to derive the above result. Please help me to derive the above result.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write $\;m^{m+1}-1=m(m^m-1)+m-1$.

Comment: Sir, do you mean that remainder i.e. $ m-1$ is the GCD?

Comment: In the present case, yes. Indeed $m-1$ is a common divisor of both. Conversely, writing $\;m-1=m^{m+1}-1-m(m^m-1)\;$ shows a common divisor of both is a divisor of $m-1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ $ No insight insight is needed, just mechanically apply the Euclidean algorithm.

Note $\ {\rm mod}\,\ n^n\!-1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n^n}\equiv\color{#c00} 1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{n^{1+n}} =\, n\, \color{#c00}{n^n}\equiv\, \color{#0a0}n$

So by the Euclidean algorithm $\ (\color{#0a0}{n^{1+n}}\!-1,n^n\!-1) = (\color{#0a0}n-1,n^n-1) = n-1$

**Remark** $\  $ As a general rule of thumb, to simplify a gcd try modding out the largest argument by the smallest one (i.e. apply the reduction step in the Euclidean algorithm). As above, this may resolve the problem in a few steps (esp. for problems that were "designed" to be easy)

Comment: Your method is good sir

Answer (score 1):

$(2016^{2017}-1)-(2016^{2016}-1)=$
$(2016^{2017})-(2016^{2016})=$
$2016\times{(2016^{2016})}-(2016^{2016})=$
$$(2016^{2016})*(2016-1)$$  Let $A=2016^{2017}
-1$,$B=2016^{2017}-1, C=2016^{2016}$.
As $gcd(A,C)=1,gcd(B,C)=1$  Therefore, $gcd(A,B)=2016-1=2015$

Comment: Nice method sir

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention, a general result holds as follows:

$$\forall a > 1\text{, gcd}(a^m-1, a^n-1) = (a^{\text{gcd}(m,n)}-1)$$

where $m, n$ are positive integers.

Have fun proving this one now.